# Converting a pd.Series into a 2D np.array without stacking two columns together in order to include the index of the columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, multidimensional-array

I want to figure out if there is a better way to convert a *pd.series* along with the index into a *2D numpy array*.

I have a dataframe accruing by a subset of a dataframe with `sub_frame=frame.loc[:,vial_columns].copy()`
This outputs the following series:

```
Out[91]: 
vial_10    False
vial_20    False
vial_30    False
vial_40    False
vial_50    False
vial_60    False
vial_70    False
dtype: bool
```

where `vial_XX` is the header of the column. I would like to wrap all of this into a 2D np.array. My current solution does the job but in an **inelegant** way:

```
np_vial=np.column_stack((np.array(vial_columns),sub_frame[vial_columns].isna().all().to_numpy()))

Out[92]: 
array([['vial_10', 'False'],
       ['vial_20', 'False'],
       ['vial_30', 'False'],
       ['vial_40', 'False'],
       ['vial_50', 'False'],
       ['vial_60', 'False'],
       ['vial_70', 'False']], dtype='<U18')
```

Is there a `pandas` or `numpy` `method` that gives this kind of output, something **smarter** than what I used above?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: `sub_frame.reset_index().to_numpy()` ..?

Comment: In case it isn't obvious the recommended `reset_index` creates a `DataFrame` that includes the index as the first column.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `reset_index`?

```py
>>> sub_frame.reset_index().values
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
print(sub_frame.reset_index().values.astype(str))
```